# How to convert this date format into DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: python, json, datetime, web-scraping, decoding

I am scraping web series data from `JSON` and `lists` using python. the problem is with date and time.
I got a function to convert the `duration` format

```
def get_duration(secs):
    hour = int(secs/3600)
    secs = secs - hour*3600
    minute = int(secs/60)
    if hour == 0:
        return "00:" + str(minute)
    elif len(str(hour)) == 1:
        return "0" + str(hour) + ":" + str(minute)
    return str(hour) + ":" + str(minute)
```

The output is `00:29` which is correct.

But how can I convert `broadCastDate` to DD-MM-YYYY format

Here is the Data

```
"items": [
   {
     "duration": 1778,
     "startDate": 1555893000,
     "endDate": 4102424940,
     "broadCastDate": 1555939800,
   }
]
```

The Broadcast Date on the website is **22 Apr 2019**, so need a function to get this type of output.

Answer (score 1):

That value looks like a timestamp so you could use [`datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) to convert to a `datetime` object and then [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to output in the format you want:

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.fromtimestamp(1555939800)
print(d.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

Output:

```
22-04-2019
```

Answer (score 1):

The original question is slightly unclear about the final desired format. If you would like "22 Apr 2019" then the required format string is "%d %b %Y"

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.fromtimestamp(1555939800)
print(d.strftime('%d %b %Y'))
```

Output:

```
22 Apr 2019
```